# What to do when test data takes up most of repo size?

Tags: testing, csv

TL;DR: Given a repo with a lot of big fixture tests, when should I look for a solution where the golden files are not part of the repo anymore? Where should they be stored?

### The setup

- Testing a complex data processing project with very diverse input sources
- Around 10^2 CSV files as fixture tests, each a few MB in size (Git LFS).

  - These tests aim to be an exhaustive sample of the currently expected & supported inputs to the system, and the manually validated correct outputs.
  - So far, these tests allowed us to create a high quality business logic core for our system.
- Current workflow:

  - About every week, a column in each file is changed or added, or a new file is added.
  - Column changes are typically because of code changes (which usually arise from a change or new feature in the specs.
  - New files are typically added as regression tests for testing new input scenarios.
  - We already have good tooling to manually inspect and approve the diffs. This part is working well.

### Pain points

- Biggest pain point: Merge conflicts when two different columns are changed. (This is tedious because the conflict only arises because merging in git is line based, not CSV column based.)
- Inspecting changes in code reviews on Gitlab/Github/... is hard, since our tooling to look at the diffs is homegrown.
- Repo size is a few GB.

  - This makes cloning and completely checking out the repo a hard task.
  - Similarly, `git log -p` takes a long time and can clutter everything for those users who have activated automatic git lfs checkout.

### Incomplete ideas to deal with this

- Moving from CSV to an external database. Downside: DB access while testing necessary, DB maintenance, need to worry about keeping DB migrations in sync with code changes
- Developing a CSV diff & merging tool that works with git. Downside: Dev effort, doesn't solve repo size issue

### Questions

- Is this a common pattern in larger code bases that deal with data processing?
- Is this a sign of a deeper, fundamental error in the chosen testing approach?
- Are there tools and methodologies out there that can support the current workflow and make it easier?

EDIT: Clarified several points that were asked about in the comments, in particular I believe I used the term "golden test" incorrectly.

Comment: "Repo size approaches 1 GB" - shouldn't Git LFS allow a lot larger repos? 1GB is a still a size where you usually don't need LFS for.

Comment: @DocBrown, yes, and I agree that it's perfectly ok to argue that repo size is not a problem with Git LFS. However, there are some aspects to repo size that Git LFS doesn't solve completely, e.g. the size of the checked out tree, or the time it takes to clone the repo, or lags when doing `git log -p` (depending on LFS config).

Comment: If you have a certain amount of test data to manage, it won't magically decrease by switching the tool. Git LFS is a solution which aims exactly for you use case. For example, the size of the checked out tree becomes a lot smaller except for the machine where your characterization tests will be run (should not be everyones machine). Git LFS is something recommended for repos from 5 to 20GB, so don't expect to develop something better on your own easily.

Comment: ... column-oriented test data should be handled like binary files - never ever change them in parallel, to avoid the need for merges. Instead, make people lock them before changing them (maybe establish an "organizational lock", only one or two members are allowed to change the files directly).

Comment: ... for your "code-review" issue, one has to look into the process a little bit more deeper, how the files are changed ( I guess there is some generation process involved) and what kind of changes really require a manual comparison between different versions of the data. Maybe you can to create a few small tools allowing you to exclude certain "new" columns from a comparison. And after assessing that a certain change in the data is justified, you may update test data by replacing the related files, no need to fiddle around with merges.

Comment: Would you be open to using a different file format than CSV? Perhaps use JSON, and part of the test process takes the JSON files and converts them to CSV, before passing the CSV to the test.

Comment: And 10^2 CSV files is only 100, which isn't a terrible number of files to deal with.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: do you think two JSON files are easier to compare with each other than two CSV files, in case data of one column has changed? And the file size will definitely become a lot larger.

Comment: > .. column-oriented test data should be handled like binary files
From one perspective, I can completely agree. From the perspective of the content, though, the intent behind changing two different columns at the same time is obvious, so it should be possible to merge them in principle. It is just a matter of tooling.

Comment: > - never ever change them in parallel, to avoid the need for merges

The need to do so arises externally, because two features might be developed at the same time.

Comment: @Turion how long is it taking to clone the repo, or run `git log -p`, or other tasks that "take a long time"? How often does your team do those things?

Comment: A formatted JSON file will have one value per line, so yes, I guess merging will be easier. But file size will increase, I guess by a small constant factor.

Comment: Meta: There are a lot of good suggestions in the comments, how about making answers from them?

Comment: @mmathis Running `git log -p` is certainly daily business :) but I guess one option is to rethink the git lfs setup, such that one doesn't always see the diff of the content, but just the diff of the hash.

Comment: Do these tests bring actual value? is the cost of maintaining them lower than the cost of the bugs they help find? The point of these "golden masters" should be as a source of well validated, trusted, result data. If these are updated every week, are they really trust worthy? If you are just committing the current output of the program, will the test actually fail if there is an error?

Comment: *"But file size will increase, I guess by a small constant factor"* - well, is a factor of 2 to 4 small? Try it out. And if you have to merge 5000 lines in a CSV where one column changed, or 5000 lines in a 50000 line JSON where every 10th line changes - you will end up exchanging one file by the other in total, I am sure you won't do this line-by-line.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. Let's back up. What was the goal when you introduced the golden tests (characterization tests) in the first place? What were you trying to do? The idea with these was to use them when the correct behavior of a legacy system is unknown/undocumented, so that you can in some way characterize what it *is* currently doing, so that you can safely shuffle the "insides" of the code in preparation for incrementally evolving the system, or to add an interaction point for an extension, etc. Was something like that the plan?

Comment: @DocBrown: JSON files will be easier provided they are formatted with proper indentation. Easier in relative terms, but "easier in absolute terms" is debatable. But, nothing says like doing. It all depends on the nature of the changes.

Comment: Ah I guess I've misunderstood what golden tests really are. After reading more on the topic, my impression is that the tests are in fact _fixture tests_.

Comment: Is the test/fixture data generatable or composable? Which means: Do you really need multiple hard-copies of the data? Or are there for example multiple files of 1MB which are 99% equal with a 1% difference? If that is the case you might be able to store the 1% separately and re-use the 99%. If there are constantly repeated parts (like headers/intro's) you may implement some kind of template syntax to merge those headers automatically upfront.

Comment: The files are all very different, only the first line (the CSV header) is the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a common pattern in larger code bases that deal with data processing?

Yes. When starting out developing a processing pipeline, checking some "real" inputs against some known good outputs is probably the simplest test strategy, especially if unfamiliar with unit testing and TDD.

> Is this a sign of a deeper, fundamental error in the chosen testing approach?

Yes, there are many issues with relying *only* on characterisation tests:

- As the pipeline complexity increases, the complexity of maintaining the tests grows with something like O(total number of possible paths through the code), even if a lot of those paths are never traversed. In a unit tested code base, the complexity should grow close to linear with the number of *branches* in the code. This complexity means that as the test suite grows, developers pretty quickly have to reduce testing rigour to get anything done. What ends up happening is that they will do the pipeline change, reprocess everything, briefly check that the output looks sane, and commit the result as job done. This normalises deviance, since "looks sane" is a far cry from a good test.
- New developers have almost zero chance of grasping the evolution of tests, since the tests are not in any way self-explanatory, just a bunch of CSVs.
- Test isolation goes out the window — a small fix somewhere in the internals could mean changing a *lot* of tests.
- For any but a trivial pipeline they are several orders of magnitude slower than unit tests.

> Are there tools and methodologies out there that can support the current workflow and make it easier?

Linux distros typically come with GNU Coreutils, which can do a lot of text processing really fast. You could also look into the many solutions for transposing ("flipping the table on its side") the CSV, to be able to diff in a column-based fashion.

Finally, diversify your test strategy. Yes, you definitely want *some* end-to-end tests, but not for every single branch in your code. It's simply unsustainable. You'll want unit tests for your business rules and branches. If you can run your tests in a reasonable time you should probably look into mutation testing as well. It doesn't require writing any more tests, and is good at discovering missing tests (independently of code coverage, which you should also generate to get a baseline for how you're doing).

Comment: We do in fact have a big unit test suite as well, and we are also working on translating every identified feature in the fixture tests into a unit test.